# Should velocity influence the teams commitment in scrum

Tags: velocity, scrum

At the end of the sprintplanning when commititng to the work that will be done in the coming sprint is it a good idea to keep the velocity in mind?

For example when the team wants to commit to a number of user stories estimated as 10 story points while having an average velocity of 7. Should the commitment be adjusted to better match the velocity?

To me it seems [Parkinson's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law) is just about to strike.

Isn't it a better idea to keep the velocity number hidden for the team and only use it to estimate when a certain feautre/story will be done?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to keep velocity in mind at the START of Sprint Planning, not the end.

Velocity is a guide to the Development Team. For example, with a velocity of 15, they will consider taking that total number of Story Points into a Sprint. However, as part of Sprint Planning, they break those stories down in to tasks. It's only at this point, they get a clear picture of what they can do in the upcoming sprint. It may be 10 Story Points, it may be 20 Story Points. Velocity is just a guide.

Can I also add that hiding things from the Development Team is a really bad idea. One of the pillars of Scrum is transparency.

Also, the latest version of the Scrum Guide has dropped all reference to the word 'commitment'. We now, more accurately, use the word 'forecast'.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the track history of the team and their velocity over the past few sprints.  So if they have been averaging 7 for a while, then accepting a 10 story is setting the team up to fail.

A minor correction, we no longer use the term "commitment" as it gets misinterpreted by management and teams suffer "death marches" if they don't meet their commitment; albeit they achieved 95% of the sprint goal.  Instead we use the word **forecast** as we can never guarantee success based on uncertainty, complexity and unexpected events.

Try break down the story into smaller stories so the team can achieve them, however encourage them to do better each sprint and push a little harder each sprint.  Thus in a retrospective, keep asking "what can we do to improve and do more?"  Be realistic what the team feels.

In your sprint planning, does the team feel they can really achieve it,  if so go for it.  If not then rethink how you will tackle such a big story or break it down to deliver an increment that adds value.

Never hide things from the team,  Scrum is about transparency, openness and a healthy working environment.  If you start hiding things, the team will start hiding things from you too.

Answer (score 0):

We can keep velocity as a baseline to new story points for the next sprint, however it is no mandatory and it will impact the teams commitment. Each team is comparable to itself. We can use velocity to compare our new story points and try improve our self and speed up the delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is a good measure, and can be *forecasted* across the span of the Sprint, based on past performance/velocity. A Sprint usually allows for a buffer in the estimates of velocity, so that unforeseen circumstances may be taken into account. This buffer is based on historical data, upcoming PTO, etc.

We can look at this question both from a Product-based team and a Service-based team's perspective. For a product team, the requirements going into a sprint may be more flexible than a service team (which might deal with clients who are not very flexible).

Ideally, the team have a velocity in mind during Backlog Grooming itself - this allows the Scrum team to pull in stories from the backlog that they know they will be expected to finish on time. Sprint Planning is where the production team discusses the nuances of these groomed/sized user stories further to get a better understanding of the functional requirements.